# Markers only mapping to half of globe

Tags: three.js

So I have a globe with a map texture around it, and Markers are mapped based on the Latitude Longitude for each location.

I am trying to figure out how the mappings work.... I noticed only half of the globe is being used. If I try to move one of the markers manually by adding pixels, I cannot get the marker to go past the half of the earth.... you can see the "seam" that I am unable to get passed here next to the EAS marker:

[image]

My three JS code:

```
EarthView3D.Init = function (siteObjects, animateCallback) {

    const EARTH_RADIUS = 225;
    const EARTH_SEGMENTS = 75;
    const EARTH_RINGS = 75;

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000);
    camera.position.set(-70, 375, 500);
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, Infinity);
    camera.add(light);

    scene.add(camera);

    // Starfield
    var starGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1000, 50, 50); //basically creates another sphere around the earth's sphere, and covers it in starfield image.
    var starMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        map: new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(Global.basePath + 'Content/images/galaxy_starfield.png'),
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        shininess: 0
    });
    var starField = new THREE.Mesh(starGeometry, starMaterial);
    scene.add(starField);

    //paths to each of the texture images.
    var earthNoCloudsTex = Global.basePath + 'Content/images/earth_no_clouds_12k.jpg';
    var earthDarkTex = Global.basePath + 'Content/images/earth_dark_12k.jpg';
    var earthDarkInvertTex = Global.basePath + 'Content/images/earth_dark_invert_12k.jpg';
    var earthRedTex = Global.basePath + 'Content/images/earth_dark_red_12k.jpg';

    // Set to default texture, earth with no clouds.
    var currentTexture = earthNoCloudsTex;

    //Create the Earth's sphere and give it an initial texture image
    var earthSphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(EARTH_RADIUS, EARTH_SEGMENTS, EARTH_RINGS);
    var earthMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(Global.basePath + 'Content/images/earth_no_clouds_12k.jpg')
    });
    var theEarth = new THREE.Mesh(earthSphere, earthMaterial); //mesh them together, to create the earth.
    scene.add(theEarth); //add earth to the scene.

    //Adding 1st atmosphere, inner
    var innerAtmosphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(EARTH_RADIUS, EARTH_SEGMENTS, EARTH_RINGS);
    var atmosMaterial = THREEx.createAtmosphereMaterial();
    atmosMaterial.uniforms.glowColor.value.set(0x00b3ff);
    atmosMaterial.uniforms.coeficient.value = 1;
    atmosMaterial.uniforms.power.value = 1.8;
    var atmosMesh = new THREE.Mesh(innerAtmosphere, atmosMaterial);
    atmosMesh.scale.multiplyScalar(1.001);
    scene.add(atmosMesh);

    //Adding 2nd atmosphere, the outer faded looking ring around inner atmosphere. 
    var outerAtmosphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(EARTH_RADIUS, EARTH_SEGMENTS, EARTH_RINGS);
    var atmosMaterial2 = THREEx.createAtmosphereMaterial();
    atmosMaterial2.side = THREE.BackSide;
    atmosMaterial2.uniforms.glowColor.value.set(0x00b3ff);
    atmosMaterial2.uniforms.coeficient.value = .800;
    atmosMaterial2.uniforms.power.value = 4.0;
    var atmosMesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(outerAtmosphere, atmosMaterial2);
    atmosMesh2.scale.multiplyScalar(1.06);
    scene.add(atmosMesh2);

    //Add toggle click event for changing earth background texture
    $('.texture_change_button').on("click", function (e) {
        //figure out which button was clicked
        var buttonClicked = $(this).attr('id');
        //disable all currently disabled buttons before disabling another
        $(":disabled").attr('disabled', false);
        //disable button clicked so that it can't be clicked twice.
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        //depending on the id of the buttonClicked, update the currentTexture
        switch (buttonClicked) {
            case 'earth_no_clouds_button':
                currentTexture = earthNoCloudsTex;
                break;
            case 'earth_dark_button':
                currentTexture = earthDarkTex;
                break;
            case 'earth_dark_invert_button':
                currentTexture = earthDarkInvertTex;
                break;
            case 'earth_red_button':
                currentTexture = earthRedTex;
        }
        //switch out the image with new currentTexture
        earthMaterial.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(currentTexture);
        theEarth.material.needsUpdate = true;
        scene.add(theEarth);
    });

    // Add siteObjects to Earth
    for (var i = 0; i < siteObjects.length; i++) {

        var siteID = siteObjects[i].SiteID;
        var name = siteObjects[i].Name;
        var lat = siteObjects[i].LAT;
        var lon = siteObjects[i].LON;
        var status = siteObjects[i].Status;

        // Create dot for each site
        var siteDiv = document.createElement('div');
        siteDiv.setAttribute("id", name);

        //set data attributes to later use when clicking dot.
        siteDiv.setAttribute("data-siteid", siteID);

        siteDiv.setAttribute("title", name);
        siteDiv.className = status.toLowerCase() == "fmc" ? "site_status fmc" :
            status.toLowerCase() == "pmc" ? "site_status pmc" :
                "site_status nmc";

        //Create label to append to each site's dot
        var siteDivLabel = document.createElement('label');
        siteDivLabel.setAttribute("id", name + '_label');
        siteDivLabel.setAttribute("title", name + ' label');
        siteDivLabel.textContent = name;

        //Setting the label's class (Some labels need to display on different sides of the dot so that all can be seen in initial view.)
        if (siteID == 6 || siteID == 9) { // 6 is BUckley, 9 is COD
            siteDivLabel.className = 'label_top_right earth_view_label';
        } else if (siteID == 12 || siteID == 20 || siteID == 19) { // 12 is FGA, 20 is PAFB, 19 is MDIOC
            siteDivLabel.className = 'label_bottom_right earth_view_label';
        } else if (siteID == 8) { // 8 is CMD
            siteDivLabel.className = 'label_bottom_left earth_view_label';
        } else {
            siteDivLabel.className = 'label_top_left earth_view_label';
        }
        siteDiv.appendChild(siteDivLabel);

        var siteDot = new THREE.CSS2DObject(siteDiv);

        siteDiv.parent = siteDot;

        siteDot.element.style.cursor = "pointer";

        // Add click event for each dot/label that takes them to the site section for the dashboard homepage.
        siteDot.element.onclick = function () {
            var siteSK = $(this).data('siteid');

            EarthView3D.Edit(siteSK);
        };

        var sitePosition = EarthView3D.CalcPosFromLatLonRad(lat, lon, EARTH_RADIUS);
        // Some code to slightly move certain site markers around from their original position so that they don't overlap each other too much.
        if (siteID == 5) { // 5 is boulder
            siteDot.position.set(sitePosition[0] - 1, sitePosition[1] + 1, Math.abs(sitePosition[2]));
        } else if (siteID == 8) { // 8 is CMD
            siteDot.position.set(sitePosition[0] - 1, sitePosition[1] - 1, Math.abs(sitePosition[2]));
        } else if (siteID == 11) { //11 is EAS
            siteDot.position.set(sitePosition[0], sitePosition[1] + 1, Math.abs(sitePosition[2]));
        }else if (siteID == 20) { // 20 is PAFB
            siteDot.position.set(sitePosition[0] + 1, sitePosition[1] - 6, Math.abs(sitePosition[2]));
        } else if (siteID == 19) { // 19 is MDIOC
            siteDot.position.set(sitePosition[0] + 5, sitePosition[1] + 4, Math.abs(sitePosition[2]));
        } else if (siteID == 6) { // 6 is Buckley
            siteDot.position.set(sitePosition[0] + 2, sitePosition[1] + 3, Math.abs(sitePosition[2]));
        } else {
            siteDot.position.set(sitePosition[0], sitePosition[1], Math.abs(sitePosition[2]));
        }
        scene.add(siteDot);
    }

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
    renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 0);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    var earthContainer = document.getElementById('earth_container');
    earthContainer.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    labelRenderer = new THREE.CSS2DRenderer();
    labelRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    labelRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    labelRenderer.domElement.style.top = 0;
    document.body.appendChild(labelRenderer.domElement);

    // For rotation and mouse controls
    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, labelRenderer.domElement);
    controls.minDistance = 400;
    controls.maxDistance = 800;
    animateCallback(siteObjects); //Running Animate right after Init.
};
```

The code that maps the lat and lon values to a marker position:

```
EarthView3D.CalcPosFromLatLonRad = function (lat, lon, radius) {

    var phi = (90 - lat) * (Math.PI / 180)
    var theta = (lon + 180) * (Math.PI / 180)

    x = -((radius) * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta))
    z = ((radius) * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta))
    y = ((radius) * Math.cos(phi))

    return [x, y, z];
};
```

Comment: Usually Latitude is in the `[-90, 90]` range, while Longitude is in the `[-180, 180]` range. Is that not what you're experiencing? What do you mean you can't get the marker to go past the half of the Earth? Also, please try to simplify your code so it only focuses on the problem at hand: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

It might be better to apply additional translations via CSS transform by implementing `onAfterRender` callback, if you'd like to move the markers two-dimensionally on the screen, as follows.

```
    var sitePosition = EarthView3D.CalcPosFromLatLonRad(lat, lon, EARTH_RADIUS);
    // Some code to slightly move certain site markers around from their original position so that they don't overlap each other too much.
    /*if (siteID == 5) { // 5 is boulder
        siteDot.position.set(sitePosition[0] - 1, sitePosition[1] + 1, Math.abs(sitePosition[2]));
    } else if (siteID == 8) { // 8 is CMD
        siteDot.position.set(sitePosition[0] - 1, sitePosition[1] - 1, Math.abs(sitePosition[2]));
    } else if (siteID == 11) { //11 is EAS
        siteDot.position.set(sitePosition[0], sitePosition[1] + 1, Math.abs(sitePosition[2]));
    }else if (siteID == 20) { // 20 is PAFB
        siteDot.position.set(sitePosition[0] + 1, sitePosition[1] - 6, Math.abs(sitePosition[2]));
    } else if (siteID == 19) { // 19 is MDIOC
        siteDot.position.set(sitePosition[0] + 5, sitePosition[1] + 4, Math.abs(sitePosition[2]));
    } else if (siteID == 6) { // 6 is Buckley
        siteDot.position.set(sitePosition[0] + 2, sitePosition[1] + 3, Math.abs(sitePosition[2]));
    } else {
        siteDot.position.set(sitePosition[0], sitePosition[1], Math.abs(sitePosition[2]));
    }*/

    siteDot.position.set(sitePosition[0], sitePosition[1], sitePosition[2]);

    var siteShift = '';
    switch(siteID) {
        case 5: // 5 is boulder
            siteShift = 'translate(-1px,1px)'; break;
        case 8: // 8 is CMD
            siteShift = 'translate(-1px,-1px)'; break;
        case 11: //11 is EAS
            siteShift = 'translate(0px,-1px)'; break;
        case 20: // 20 is PAFB
            siteShift = 'translate(1px,-6px)'; break;
        case 19: // 19 is MDIOC
            siteShift = 'translate(5px,4px)'; break;
        case 6: // 6 is Buckley
            siteShift = 'translate(2px,3px)'; break;
        default: 
            break;
    }
    siteDiv.setAttribute('data-shift', siteShift); 

    siteDot.onAfterRender = function(renderer, scene, camera) {
        let pos = new THREE.Vector3();
        pos.setFromMatrixPosition( this.matrixWorld );
        if (camera.position.dot(pos) < pos.lengthSq()) {
            // Hide unreachable markers.
            this.element.style.display = 'none'; 
        }
        else {
            // Shift markers on the screen.
            this.element.style.transform = this.element.getAttribute('data-shift') + ' ' + this.element.style.transform;
        } 
    };
    scene.add(siteDot);
```